# Unable to train model using gpu on M1 Mac

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

How to reproduce the behaviour

install space for apple , select model training option and follow the on screen instructions.

generate config files for model training.

Declare your training and testing corpus in base_config file then auto fill the to generate the final config file.

python -m spacy init fill-config base_config.cfg config.cfg

python -m spacy train config/config.cfg -g 0 --output trf_model-2

Your Environment

Operating System: MacOS 12.4
Python Version Used: 3.10
spaCy Version Used: 3.4.0
Environment Information: -
spaCy version: 3.4.0
Platform: macOS-12.4-arm64-arm-64bit
Python version: 3.10.5
Pipelines: en_core_web_trf (3.4.0)
While I'm trying to train the model using gpu on m1 Mac got this error

RuntimeError: invalid gradient at index 0 - expected device cpu but got mps:0

Answer (score 0):

The motel GPU support for Apple silicon M1 Mac processor is not there in spacy yet,
We have to wait till the spacy team provides proper support for apple silicon based hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, there's no GPU support for training on Apple Silicon at this time. However, spaCy can leverage some accelerations on Apple Silicon if the [thinc-apple-ops](https://github.com/explosion/thinc-apple-ops) module is installed. You can specify it as an option when installing spaCy.

```
pip install spacy[apple]
```